# Adding String values in NSMutableArray in IOS

Tags: ios

I am working with an IOS application in which I add string values ,which i am getting as PhotoiD in array,later after I want to use this stored photoid value in my application.
Below is the code in which I am trying to store the string value in array->

```
//NSMutableArray *array;
//NSString *photoID;

for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
{
    [array addObject:photoID];    
}
```

But i am not getting the right output when use this array as below code

```
for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",array[i]);    
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Please help me out from this problem.

Thanks Rausi..

Comment: add your output here .

Comment: have you allocated your array object?

Comment: Check your loop condition in 1st code snippet. if array is initially empty the loop won't execute at all.

Comment: @maverick,,yes  i have allocated the array in viewdidload,but still it does not work.

Comment: @Darshan: i am not getting any output,my control does not go inside the loop,so it does not give any output

Comment: @Vladimir is correct - your first code snippet makes no sense, even if `array` is not empty - it will add `array count` instances of your string to the array

Comment: @Rausi please check what Vladimir and Paulw11 comments. In your first loop, array have no element, so control does not goes inside the first loop.

Comment: @Paulw11 , sir how can i add the strings in that array,and get the value of string in another code snippet,,please help me out.what should i do??

Comment: To add a string to the array, simply `[array addObject:photoID];`  but not in a loop.  Your second snippet is fine for retrieving the values

Answer (score 1):

Your "array" is empty array. The loop run from 0 to 0. This is skip code block in your loop.
You can use below code:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSString *photoID     = @"Input value photoID";

[array addObject:photoID];
NSLog(@"%@",array);

[array release];
```

Sorry, because my english is not good. :).

Comment: thanks for your answer,but when i am adding string in array by your method and  then print the value of array, i got two different values,that photoid and array values are different.,is there any way by which i can get the value of array at the particular position by using the loop.??

Comment: If you are compiling with ARC (you probably are unless this is an old project) then you don't want the [array release]

Comment: You can use:     for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:i]);
    }. You can delete [array release] if you use ARC :)

Comment: i only get the values of array in only that loop.,when i want to achieve the value of array in other loop,nothing i get.Do u have any idea how i do that??

Comment: I don't understand that you want doing. Can you write your code at here? I will help you.

Comment: @hoptqVN.dev to achieve the thing you have create global array, like declare in .h.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 I think if I use array at the difference block code, i will create a global variable. But at there, i only need a local variable.

Comment: Then what the mean of <i only get the values of array in only that loop.,when i want to achieve the value of array in other loop,nothing i get.Do u have any idea how i do that??> ??

Comment: Other loop can put before "[array release]" and after "NSLog()" or use autorelease (if non ARC). Problem at here is [array release]. I understood Rausi s' question. Thanks Rajneesh071.

Answer (score 0):

Issue IS with your code, because you just initialise your array and using it in a loop.
Initially array count is zero, so loop code will not execute.

```
 for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
```

So just remove your loop if you want to add object.